# How do you make Google search acknowledge a specific configuration of whitespace?

Tags: google-search

If you search for `"vi v i" chord progression`, some results will highlight `vi v i`, but a good deal of other results will show things like `v iv i` or even `vi vi`.

[image: An example of such a search]

How do you force the search so the result only returns `vi v i`?

Comment: Upvoted because it's a good question, and I'm hoping someone has an answer.  My experience is that Google is notoriously bad at this sort of thing.  It chokes badly on anything less than full-word searches.